# Uvicorn/FastAPI - Execute code on a single worker only

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

Is it possible to run code on only a specific worker in Uvicorn?

I have the following functions currently being executed on application startup.

```py
@app.on_event('startup')
async def app_startup():
    asyncio.create_task(check_idle())
    asyncio.create_task(calculate_eta())
```

However, I'd only like a single worker (e.g. worker 0) to run those functions to avoid straining the database.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you on? Chances are you should use the database's discretionary lock mechanism instead.

Comment: @AKX I'm using Postgres with Tortoise ORM. I suppose, although the functions, especially check_idle() just means all 8 workers will be performing the same table deletion code, which will only make a difference on one execution.

Comment: I have run into this issue too, and depending on what the functions are doing you could split it up into a different process and store the result (if any) in redis, mongo etc instead of running it on your web app

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS You can use eg pg_try_advisory_xact_lock and a transaction to ensure only one worker does the thing.

Comment: You can limit the parallel tasks with asyncio using `asyncio.Semaphore`

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote something for this:

The idea is to use the `pid` of a uvicorn worker as a "uniquifier".

I have a `UniqueWorker` class, which basically creates in every process a worker, tho only one gets randomly assigned (probably the last one who writes to the `pid` file)

It's not very cool that the function still gets called everytime, but at least the part, which you don't want to be executed often isn't called.
I think it's a tolerable overhead.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
from functools import cached_property


class UniqueWorker:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = Path(path)
        self.id = str(os.getpid())
        self._set_id()

    def _set_id(self):
        """create the path to the pid file if it doesn't exist, 
        write the pid to the file
        """
        if self.path.exists():
            self.path.parents[0].mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        with open(self.path, "w") as f:
            f.write(self.id)

    @cached_property
    def is_assiged(self):
        """check if the worker in this process has been assigned 
        as the unique worker
        """
        with open(self.path, "r") as f:
            assigned_worker = f.read()

        return assigned_worker == self.id

# bake this badboy into a decorator
def by_one_worker(worker_pid_path):
    unique_worker = UniqueWorker(worker_pid_path)

    def deco(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if not unique_worker.is_assiged:
                return

            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped

    return deco

# then with fastapi_utils we can:
from fastapi_utils.tasks import repeat_every

@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=2)
@by_one_worker("/dev/shm/path/to/you/pid/sync/file")
def do_something_repeatable():
    print("blabla I love decorator n stuff")
```

Also available in my package:

```
pip3 install --user dimfred
from dimfred.fastapi_utils import by_one_worker
```

Comment: Isn't this very racy? If one worker reads before the last one writes, you'll have this executing on two different workers.

Comment: Yes it is and this is also what happens. Sometimes one decorator overrides the other one. Good thing is that only one pid in the end will be in the file. So in the end the bahavior is as it should be.
Tho I am not sure whether one could get the same behavior as with prints, e.g. that 2 pids get fused into one number or something, that could be too, but I have never seen something like this. Tbh I don't use this anymore, started to do something like this but with celery tasks, with a redis based mutex.